# Which is he most secure method of passing values to Ajax

Tags: jquery

What is the most secure method of passing values through a jQuery AJAX function?

I am currently serialising the whole form, is this secure or are there better ways of doing it?

This is the Ajax call I am currently using

```
 function logIn() 
      { 
          jQuery.ajax({ 
           type: "POST", 
           url: "ajax/index_login.php", 
           data: $('#login').serialize(), 
           cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
                if(response == 'valid'){
                    document.location.href = '/main_menu.php';
                }else{
                    $('#index_error').html('Incorrect username or password');
                }
             }
       }); 
 }
```

I just want to make sure that the values can't be intercepted in some way via a url or via the browser as they are passed to the server.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secure"? Are you talking about security of the network transport, which would normally be handled by SSL? Or are you talking about security of your server side code, which isn't related to your front end code? You'll have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: I've updated the question, I just want to make it as hard as possible for the data to be intercepted via the browser

Comment: But now what do you mean by "intercepted by the browser"? The browser *is* responsible for making the request. In order for it to work it all, your request *must* be handled by the browser.

Comment: can the values in the serialised form be intercepted in anyway using something like firebug or console via the browser, thats what I meant

Comment: Yes, definitely, and there is *nothing* you can do to prevent that. Your application must be designed knowing that the end user has complete control over the data sent to and from your site.

Comment: ok, thanks, I just wanted to check if there wasn't anything wrong with using the method I've used or if there was a better, more secure way.  I will just make sure the passed values are validated and sanitised before passing to the server or DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much you can do to secure your front-end form. You can add all kinds of validation, but users can disable javascript, modify the form attributes in the DOM, etc. What you should do is validate the data on your server, and make sure it looks reasonable before you do anything serious with it.

There's also the issue of network security, like Greg mentioned in a comment above, but I don't know as much about that.

EDIT: If you don't want people snooping on the request in-flight, be sure to serve your site over https.

Comment: Thanks, the network is secure (it's a well known health care company) and https will be used but they will be penetration testing the site so I need it to be as secure as possible.  I guess what I really wanted to know is if there is  anything wrong with the method I have used